# Starting and Stopping chromedriver once per test session

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, specflow

I have a bunch of selenium tests that run as part of specflow scenarios. I am currently starting and stopping the ChromeDriver once per feature:

```
[Binding]
public class WebBrowser
{
    public static IWebDriver Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (!FeatureContext.Current.ContainsKey("browser"))
            {
                FeatureContext.Current["browser"] = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            return (IWebDriver)FeatureContext.Current["browser"];
        }
    }

    [BeforeFeature]
    public static void Close()
    {
        if (FeatureContext.Current.ContainsKey("browser"))
        {
            Current.Close();
            ((ChromeDriver) FeatureContext.Current["browser"]).Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

The tests would run much faster if I could create and quit the chromedriver once per unit test session run rather than once per feature run.

Is there a way to configure nunit to run some code at the end of each run?

If I remove the `chromedriver.Quit()` call then:

- The Resharper test runner spins forever after running my tests never reporting the test run as complete.
- The NUnit test runner works fine but leaves a running driver window after each test session run.

It would be great if I could have some code create the chromedriver before the first test is run and stop it after the last test is run.

Update: Changed `[BeforeScenario]` to `[BeforeFeature]` - thanks to Lee for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

You are quitting the driver after each scenario not feature. If you changed [AfterScenario] to [AfterFeature] you will gain some performance increase. You can use [BeforeFeature] to set up your web driver.

Comment: Thanks Lee, the original question still remains but fixing this did increase the speed dramatically.

Comment: this is the correct answer.  you should be quitting in [AfterFeature], as this answer points out.